# 404 error when using Composer to download Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I am working my way through the Zend Framework 2 tutorial and got stuck on [page 2](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html)

I issued the following command

```
php composer.phar create-project \
--repository-url="http://packages.zendframework.com" \
zendframework/skeleton-application /home/user/zf2-tutorial
```

and provided my GitHub credentials. After a few seconds I got the following error:

> Downloading: connection...
>
> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>     The "https://api.github.com/repos/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/zipball/zf/release-2.1.0" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)

Does anyone know what the correct URL is and how do I force composer to use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not an expert(first time ZF2 install for me, but I think it's a bug on packages.zendframework.com), but I've experienced the same problem.
I made it work with the following commands(I have git installed and the OS I'm using is Debian 6).

```
git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git --recursive
$ curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
cd ZendSkeletonApplication/
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar install
```

Please see:
http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#locally
https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication#using-composer-recommended

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! It seems I did not have to use curl to get composer because composer.phar is now included in the repository.